# Releasing displayed pdf files in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, browser

I have a webbrowser control in my winforms application to display a selected pdf file, after this i want to move the pdf file to an other location.

When i trie to move the pdf file it is giving me an error that the file is in use. I tried to make the webbrowser navigate to a other page before it is moved but it still give me this error that the file is used by an other process.

How can i release this pdf file so i can just move it? Disposing the webbrowser didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can you verify that there's no zombie `AcroRd32.exe` in the background after disposing of the `WebBrowser` control? `AcroRd32.exe` zombies are quite common

Comment: After disposing there is still the AcroRd32.exe, after closing the acroRD32.exe i'm free to move the file.

Comment: @Shai - Acrobat zombies... that's awesome. I smell a sitcom.

Comment: @M.Babcock - Zombie processes that is! (-:

Comment: try navigate to about:blank and wait for navigating to complete before moving the file

Answer (score 6):

They say "Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader are designed to continue running for a few minutes after you close the browser window in which you viewed PDF files."

The workaround for this seems to be :
Copy the PDF to a temporary file and display it, and then when you navigate away, it doesn't matter if AcroRD32.exe holds onto the PDF for a few minutes because you can still do what you need with the original!

Answer (score 1):

The following code releases for me the pdf file, which was displayed in WebBrowser, so I can move it:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank")
```

Also see: [How can i delete the file that has been navigated in a webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495619/how-can-i-delete-the-file-that-has-been-navigated-in-a-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similiar problem, which was that the form with opened pdf file in browser was hidden and then a new instance of the form was opened, which triggered the same file locked error. For me Disposing of the WebBrowser control just before hiding the form helped.